# How to renew a cloudformation created API Gateway API Key

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I've created users with API Keys in a cloudformation yaml file. We want to renew one API Key but an API Key is immutable so has to be deleted and regenerated. Deleting an API Key manually and then hoping that rerunning the cloudformation script is going to replace it with no other ill effects seems like risky business. What is the recommended way to do this (I'd prefer not to drop and recreate the entire stack for availability reasons and because I only want to renew one of our API keys, not all of them)?

The only strategy I can think of right now is

- change the stack so that the name associated with the API Key in question is changed
- deploy the stack (which should delete the old API Key and create the new one)
- change the stack to revert the 1st change which should leave me with a changed API Key
  with same name
- deploy the stack

Clunky eh!

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a bit clunky, but manually deleting it, will not cause cloudformation to recreate the API key, since it has an internal state of the stack in which the key still exists.

You could simply change the resource name of the API key and update the stack, but this will only work if you can have duplicate names for API keys, which I doubt, but I could not find confirmation in the docs.

This leaves the only way to do it, in two steps (if you want to keep the same name). One to remove the old key, and a second update to create the new key. This can be achieved by simply commenting the corresponding lines in the first step and subsequently uncommenting them for the second step, or as you suggested, by changing the name of the API key and then changing it back.